# comparing indexPaths in a loop iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, compare, nsindexpath

I am trying to compare an index path in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method with an array of index paths.

```
for (n=0; n < [tempMutArrray count]; n= n+1){

     NSComparisonResult *result = [indexPath compare:[tempMutArray objectAtIndex:n];

//What I want to do is is write an if statement that executes a certain block of code 
//if the two index paths are equal, but I cant figure out how to work with an 
//NSComparisonResult. 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NSOrderedSame`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW9) and no pointer - `NSComparisonResult` is just an integer:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [indexPath compare:[tempMutArray objectAtIndex:n];

if(result == NSOrderedSame) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In the Cocoa APIs, there are some *non-class-types* in use. Most important are those from the [Foundation data types](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW9), which include

- enumerations
- typedefs for integral types
- structures

Answer (score 1):

It's just an int holding one of these values:

- NSOrderedAscending
- NSOrderedSame
- NSOrderedDescending

In your case, test for `NSOrderedSame`:

```
if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: To nitpick, `NSComparisonResult` is an `enum`, not an `int`.

Comment: No it isn't. The `NSOrdered...` values are members of the enum `_NSComparisonResult` (note the underscore prefix), but `NSComparisonResult` is a typedef of `NSInteger`, which is itself a typedef of `int`.

Comment: Apologies, i somehow overlooked that :) *(Note to self: look closely before nitpicking)*